# Ayuda con un problema de obtención del promedio de notas

Tags: java

Me piden hallar el promedio de cuatro notas ingresadas por teclado. De las cuales se elimina a menor nota y se duplica la mayor. El programa podrá calcular el promedio de n alumnos.
Sin embargo en el siguiente código no implementé la eliminación y tampoco el duplicado. El error que tengo se debe a los bucles. Si habría una forma más fácil de hacerlo le agradecería mucho.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ejer_2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String _rpt;
    int _nota=0,_cont=0;
    int _sum=0,_prom=0;
    boolean _valor=true;

    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(_valor) {
        System.out.println("Desea obtener su promedio(S/N)?: ");
        _rpt = stdIn.nextLine();
        if(_rpt.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
            _cont++;
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
                System.out.print("Ingresar nota: ");
                _nota=stdIn.nextInt();

                while(_nota<0||_nota>20) {
                    System.out.print("Valor incorrecto."
                            + "Vuelva a ingresar nota: ");
                    _nota=stdIn.nextInt();
                }//while


                //resultado de la suma
                    _sum+=_nota;


            }//for
            //obtención del promedio
            _prom=_sum/4;
        System.out.println("Su promedio es: "+_prom);
        }//if

        else if(_rpt.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.println("Fin del programa");
            _valor=false;
        }


        else {
            System.out.println("Valor no válido."
                    + "Vuelva a ingresar dato: ");
            _rpt = stdIn.nextLine();
        }//else 




    }//while
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejercicio es fácil de resolver, deberías ser capaz de hacerlo rápidamente. Solo debes sentarte a pensar un poco. He implementado todo lo que se pide y he comentado todo el código para que puedas entender mis pasos, puedes modificar el programa a tu gusto.

**Opción 1**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /**
     * Variables
     */

    // Arreglo de 4 posiciones para almacenar 4 notas
    int[] notas = new int[4];

    // Scanner para capturar datos
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Lógica del programa
     */

    // #################### Paso 1. Solicitar las 4 notas

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      // Do-while para garantizar que se ejecute al menos 1 vez
      do {
        System.out.print("Ingrese la nota #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
        notas[i] = scanner.nextInt();

        // Mostrar aviso de valor incorrecto
        if (notas[i] < 0 || notas[i] > 20)
          System.out.print("Valor incorrecto. Vuelva a ingresar la nota.\n");
      } while (notas[i] < 0 || notas[i] > 20);
    }

    // #################### Paso 2. Eliminar la menor nota y duplicar la mayor

    int min = notas[0];
    int max = notas[0];
    int minPosicion = 0;
    int maxPosicion = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
      // Menor
      if (min > notas[i]) {
        min = notas[i];
        minPosicion = i;
      }

      // Mayor
      if (max < notas[i]) {
        max = notas[i];
        maxPosicion = i;
      }
    }

    // Igualamos la menor nota a 0 para que no tenga ningún efecto en los cálculos
    notas[minPosicion] = 0;
    System.out.print("\nLa nota #" + (minPosicion + 1) + " con valor de " + min + " ha sido eliminada por ser la menor.\n");

    // Duplicamos la mayor nota
    notas[maxPosicion] *= 2;
    System.out.print("\nLa nota #" + (maxPosicion + 1) + " con valor de " + max + " ha sido duplicada por ser la mayor." +
      "\nAhora la mayor nota tiene un valor de " + notas[maxPosicion] + ".\n");

    // #################### Paso 3. Calcular el promedio

    // Sumar todas las notas
    int sumatoria = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
      sumatoria += notas[i];
    }

    // Sacar el promedio
    int promedio = sumatoria / 4;

    System.out.print("\nSumatoria de notas: " + sumatoria);
    System.out.print("\nPromedio: " + promedio);

  }

}
```

**Opción 2**

Si quieres organizar un poco el código y dividir las tareas en funciones, puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // #################### Paso 1. Solicitar las 4 notas

    int[] notas = solicitarNotas();

    // #################### Paso 2. Eliminar la menor nota y duplicar la mayor

    notas = eliminarYduplicar(notas);

    // #################### Paso 3. Calcular el promedio

    calcularPromedio(notas);

  }

  /**
   * Solicita 4 notas por teclado.
   * @return Arreglo int de 4 posiciones
   */
  public static int[] solicitarNotas() {
    // Arreglo de 4 posiciones para almacenar 4 notas
    int[] notas = new int[4];

    // Scanner para capturar datos
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      // Do-while para garantizar que se ejecute al menos 1 vez
      do {
        System.out.print("Ingrese la nota #" + (i + 1) + ": ");
        notas[i] = scanner.nextInt();

        // Mostrar aviso de valor incorrecto
        if (notas[i] < 0 || notas[i] > 20)
          System.out.print("Valor incorrecto. Vuelva a ingresar la nota.\n");
      } while (notas[i] < 0 || notas[i] > 20);
    }

    return notas;
  }

  /**
   * Elimina la menor nota y duplica la mayor nota.
   * @param notas Arreglo de notas a trabajar
   * @return Arreglo int de 4 posiciones
   */
  public static int[] eliminarYduplicar(int[] notas) {
    int min = notas[0];
    int max = notas[0];
    int minPosicion = 0;
    int maxPosicion = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
      // Menor
      if (min > notas[i]) {
        min = notas[i];
        minPosicion = i;
      }

      // Mayor
      if (max < notas[i]) {
        max = notas[i];
        maxPosicion = i;
      }
    }

    // Igualamos la menor nota a 0 para que no tenga ningún efecto en los cálculos
    notas[minPosicion] = 0;
    System.out.print("\nLa nota #" + (minPosicion + 1) + " con valor de " + min + " ha sido eliminada por ser la menor.\n");

    // Duplicamos la mayor nota
    notas[maxPosicion] *= 2;
    System.out.print("\nLa nota #" + (maxPosicion + 1) + " con valor de " + max + " ha sido duplicada por ser la mayor." +
      "\nAhora la mayor nota tiene un valor de " + notas[maxPosicion] + ".\n");

    return notas;
  }

  /**
   * Calcula el promedo de notas.
   * @param notas Arreglo de notas a trabajar
   */
  public static void calcularPromedio(int[] notas) {
    // Sumar todas las notas
    int sumatoria = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < notas.length; i++) {
      sumatoria += notas[i];
    }

    // Sacar el promedio
    int promedio = sumatoria / notas.length;

    System.out.print("\nSumatoria de notas: " + sumatoria);
    System.out.print("\nPromedio: " + promedio);
  }

}
```

**Resultado**

```
Ingrese la nota #1: 4
Ingrese la nota #2: 13
Ingrese la nota #3: 7
Ingrese la nota #4: 18

La nota #1 con valor de 4 ha sido eliminada por ser la menor.

La nota #4 con valor de 18 ha sido duplicada por ser la mayor.
Ahora la mayor nota tiene un valor de 36.

Sumatoria de notas: 56
Promedio: 14
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. La verdad es que recién estoy en el mundo de la programación. Espero algún día llegar a aprender tanto como tú. Saludos.

Comment: @rocky Me alegra haberte ayudado, puedes marcar mi respuesta como la solución a tu pregunta y votarla para que otros usuarios en el futuro sepan que realmente ha sido la solución a tu problema. Saludos.